# Which is the OpenCL library for NVIDIA K1 Shield Tablet?

Tags: android, android-ndk, opencl, nvidia

I'm trying to build an Android Application that use OpenCL library.
I compiled the application using 'libOpenCL.so' file but the application doesn't work.
Which is the OpenCL library for NVIDIA Shield Tablet?

Answer (score 1):

Nvidia has not released one. You may be able to get a CPU only runtime working by installing pocl (https://github.com/pocl/pocl) as it does have a readme file for ARM. Disclaimer: I have never done this and can't help you any further.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no OpenCL library on Tegra K1 devices. NVIDIA has not release anything realated to OpenCL on K1. Let's wait.

But that's probably not something happening soon...